# Resizing System.Windows.Forms.UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I have a Winform with size (650 * 650). 
And i want to use the same for WPF controls(using elementhost). And I want to Resize the Form to new size(550 * 650) at runtime. How can we do this?

Comment: Have you looked into the `Size` property? I'm not really sure what you're looking for here...

Comment: yes, I tried using Size Property but of no use. To be more clear, let me explain a bit more: - I have a UserControl and i want to keep it as it is. - I want to use the same UserControl for a new WPF dialog. And I want to reduce the Size of the window from its existing size to a new size at run time. I tried resetting the Size property at run time but size remains same even after doing this.

Comment: So what does the UserControl have to do with anything?

Comment: @Tom - I am resizing the Size property of the UserControl.

Comment: Well, that wasn't what you said, so you can understand the confusion. How is the sizing behaviour of the UserControl itself configured? If the control surface is set to AutoSize, you probably won't be able to set the size programmatically as it will immediately run layout again at the AutoSize dimensions.

Comment: Autosize is set to false

Comment: @singla, could you provide some code to clarify some details and relations in your application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change Width property. What's problem?

XAML:

```
<WrapPanel>
    <WindowsFormsHost>
        <wf:Button Width="650" Height="650" x:Name="Btn"/>
    </WindowsFormsHost>
</WrapPanel>
```

Code behind:

```
public TestView(IStartupPresentationModel startupModel)
{
   InitializeComponent();
   this.Btn.Click += new EventHandler(Btn_Click);
}

void Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Btn.Width = 550;
}
```